# For loop list not updating

Tags: python-3.x, string, loops

This should be a simple problem however at the moment I cannot understand why. Below is a simple code that is suppose to stripe of all strings and convert to int. However the results do not agree with what I wrote.

```
num = ('"28"', '"23"', '"35"', '"50"', 29488)
for i in num:
    if type(i) is str:
        i = i[1:-1]
        print(i)
print(num)
```

Expected output

28
23
35
50
(28, 23, 35, 50, 29488)

Actual output

28
23
35
50
('"28"', '"23"', '"35"', '"50"', 29488)

Just found out I had a tuple, when I thought it was a list...

Comment: Are you just trying to convert to int?

Comment: Modifying the variable `i` will not affect your original list. You should initialise a new, empty list and append `i` to it.

Comment: Plus, you have a tuple, not a list. Tuples are immutable

Comment: Notably though, if you mutate `i`, it will affect the original list.

Comment: @Jtcruthers True, should've clarified that.

Comment: If you do not wish to print the strings which are converted then you can use this one liner: `list(map(lambda x: int(x[1:-1]) if isinstance(x, str) else x, num))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few problems to address

1. Strings are immutable, so you're not really changing anything in the list, you're just reassigning the loop variable
2. You're not converting anything to ints, only removing characters from strings
3. If you want to be able to reassign elements within the nums, you need to use an actual list variable

For example

```
num = ['"28"', '"23"', '"35"', '"50"', 29488] 
for i, n in enumerate(num):
    if isinstance(n, str):
        num[i] = int(n.strip('"')) 
        print(n)
print(num)
```

Comment: Is there a way to do this just using for i in num: ?

Comment: If you want to maintain the index of the loop iteration separately, then yes

Answer (score 0):

- Re-assignment is missing to index position
- Tuples are immutable, can not be set values using index position.

You can refer answer given by @cricket_007, also if you want single liner list compression way then refer below -

```
num = tuple(int(n.strip('"')) if isinstance(n, str) else n for n in num)
```

Then you will get again new tuple with values converted into int.